# Windows XP Log In: Can't do it. Logon Message popup

Tags: windows-xp, login

A friend recommended this site to me. Hope you can help! I can't seem to log into Windows. 
I boot my computer. The log In screen appears. I put in my user name and password, hit OK, and the following message pops up: "The system could not log you on. Make sure your user name and domain name are correct, then type your password again. Letters in your passwords must be typed using the correct case".

NOTE: I have tried Safe Mode and the same message pops up.

Just to be clear, I am not able to get into Windows (I'm stressing this b/c I've come across some suggestions that require you to be in Windows, which doesn't help in my case).

Thanks for your assistance.

-Stranded in Toronto

Comment: Have you checked the obvious things - Caps lock off? User name and password entered correctly? I know this might seem insulting, but by double checking these things you can eliminate a lot of possibilities.

Comment: I have.  No change.

Comment: Do you use an alternate keyboard layout?  Any chance Windows is swapping them when you type in your password?

Comment: Password is blank so that's a non-issue.

Comment: Has your computer been on a company network, i.e. do you need to enter a domain before your username?

Comment: It's a home computer.  It may have been used for business in the past, however I've never been prompted to enter a domain name beofre a username.

Comment: @user33906 Is this a laptop? I came across a problem where the NUM LOCK was on causing the alphabet keys to be typing letters and the username just happened to not use those letters in the username.  Try typing your password into the username field so that you can see exactly what the computer is getting then `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-V` that into the password field.

Answer (score 0):

Since when has all this been happening?  Did you do anything just before this?

ie: Install/ Uninstall prog.
    Registry editing
    Windows repair/ System Restore
    Back-up / Recovery
    BSOD or any error (software or hardware)
    any profile changes add/subtract
    and changes in hardware
    can you logon in safemode as "ADMINISTRATOR"

do you have the Windows CD?

Did anyone use your system and now this happened?  Are their any other profiles on the computer; can you log onto them?

Need more info!